# Liferay is not generate preview for PDF file only?

Tags: imagemagick, liferay, liferay-6, ghostscript, openoffice.org

Liferay is not generating preview for PDF file only. It generates preview for all other types of files. I had linux server + liferay 6.2 GA3 + Imagemagick + Ghost + openoffice. I had running openoffice. Conversation from one file to other working fine, I have only problem for pdf file preview. Previously it was generating preview. The surprising thing is no log for PDF in machine but log for other files.

I am able to conver PDF to png whith help of convert command.

**Below are logs while uploading PDF**

tail -f /opt/trianz-portal/tomcat-7.0.42/logs/catalina.out
14:03:15,404 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-38][PollerServlet:63] No channel exists with user id 80601
14:03:15,428 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-38][status_jsp:752] No channel exists with user id 80601
14:03:18,868 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-40][PollerServlet:63] No channel exists with user id 80601
14:03:18,890 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-40][status_jsp:752] No channel exists with user id 80601
14:03:21,115 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-38][PollerServlet:63] No channel exists with user id 80601
14:03:21,138 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-38][status_jsp:752] No channel exists with user id 80601
14:03:34,851 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-33][PollerServlet:63] No channel exists with user id 50659
14:03:34,925 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-33][status_jsp:752] No channel exists with user id 50659
14:03:58,000 WARN  [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-3][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory
14:04:36,238 WARN  [ajp-bio-8009-exec-39][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory

**Below logs for other files where preview genarate successfully for other files**
14:07:19,844 WARN  [ajp-bio-8009-exec-9][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory
14:07:21,668 INFO  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][GhostscriptImpl:71] Excecuting command '/usr/local/bin/gs -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sFONTPATH/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=/opt/trianz-portal/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/liferay/document_preview/2662941.1.0-%d.png -dPDFFitPage -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r300 -dDEVICEWIDTH1000 /opt/trianz-portal/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/liferay/document_conversion/2662941.1.0.pdf '
14:07:23,429 WARN  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory
14:07:24,199 WARN  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory
14:07:24,966 WARN  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory
14:07:25,028 WARN  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory
14:07:25,180 INFO  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][PDFProcessorImpl:423] Ghostscript generated 4 preview pages for assign.doc in 3512 ms
14:07:25,194 INFO  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][GhostscriptImpl:71] Excecuting command '/usr/local/bin/gs -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sFONTPATH/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=/opt/trianz-portal/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/liferay/document_thumbnail/2662941.1.0.png -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dPDFFitPage -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r300 -dDEVICEWIDTH1000 /opt/trianz-portal/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/liferay/document_conversion/2662941.1.0.pdf '
14:07:26,360 WARN  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][RestStorageService:221] Content-Length of data stream not set, will automatically determine data length in memory
14:07:26,392 INFO  [liferay/document_library_pdf_processor-1][PDFProcessorImpl:438] Ghostscript generated a thumbnail for assign.doc in 1198 ms

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using community edition(not mentioned in question).
As per the logs,the pdf file is not even read correctly,leave alone being uploaded,due to the channel errors.As per the given thread https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/52746434 this is due to one of bugs [LPS-51390](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-51390).
It should be fixed when you update with patch for this issue.

CE does not have patching tool available.
You would need to manually do the patching by either looking for the changes for the given commit done for LPS-51390 on github or upgrade to CE GA4 Try below link for ref [Liferay Upgrade](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/upgrading-liferay)

Comment: Hi Shivam Thanks for answer My version is CE GA3. Channel errors come many time not only during file uploads. This log  also come when other file when generate preview successfully                                                         How to fix this error. Where will i get patch? Does CE has patch option?

Comment: @tushar I have edited my answer,please refer the same.